# Using qt Modeltest

Tags: qt, testing, model

I am trying to use model test for testing qt models (4.6).

I have downloaded the source but there is no pri file as per instructions so I have included the following in my project

```
CONFIG += qtestlib

SOURCES += src/main.cpp
           src/mymodel.cpp \
           modeltest/tst_modeltest.cpp \ 
           modeltest/modeltest.cpp \
           modeltest/dynamictreemodel.cpp
HEADERS += src/mymodel.h \
           modeltest/modeltest.h \
           modeltest/dynamictreemodel.h
```

But I get multiple definitions of main when I compile
This is the offending line in tst_modeltest.cpp

```
QTEST_MAIN(tst_ModelTest)
```

I have a main function

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
MyModel sstm();
ModelTest *tst = new ModelTest(&sstm);
QTableView tvs;

tvs.setModel(&sstm);
tvs.show();
return app.exec();
```

The bottom line is, how do I test my model. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried **not** including tst_modeltest.cpp in your pro file ?

By the way you should **not mix** your *test code* and *production code* !

It seems your are doing that and I strongly suggest not doing it.

Comment: Thank, Yes, I have tried that and it compiles and runs, however I dont understand how the tests are then run if the tst_modeltest.cpp is not used. Do I have to write my own?

Comment: #include <modeltest.h>
 
QDirModel *model = new QDirModel(this);
new ModelTest(model, this);                                Constructor of ModelTest will run the pre-defined tests for QDirModel. Pass your own model to constructor of this class and tests will run for your own model. As described at http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Model_Test

Comment: QTEST_MAIN(tst_ModelTest) generates a main(), so you don't have to roll your own when building the test.